# How to instantiate GoogleIdTokenVerifier properly / what does .setAudience() do?

Tags: java, android, google-signin, google-authentication

## My Guidelines

If followed [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth) Google documentation about verifying Google-Account-Tokens on the server side, but I am kinda confused.

## My Problem

```
GoogleIdTokenVerifier googleIdTokenVerifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory())
                                .setAudience(Collections.singletonList(CLIENT_ID))
                                .build();
```

In this piece of code I figured out that the `transport` and `jsonFactory` arguments can be filled as `new NetHttpTransport()` and `new JacksonFactory()` [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-credentials/blob/master/credentials-quickstart/app/src/main/java/com/google/example/credentialsbasic/MockServer.java). It also describes how to get `AudienceString`, but I couldn't figure out what it is for. I couldn't test it, but my question is if I can use it without `.setAudience()` or if I need it and what it is for.

Comment: This must match the CLIENT_ID you supplied to .requestIdToken() in the GoogleSignInOptions.Builder (see example the docs: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth ), which must match your project configuration. Here is a complete explanation: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/03/registering-oauth-clients-for-google.html

Comment: @StevenSoneff Yep, thanks mate. Got it all working now :)

Comment: OMG I was wondering what transport and jsonFactory was for ages... Google's doc is so unnecessary confusing and outdated... Talking about outdated, for anyone reading I  believe they replaced JacksonFactory with GsonFactory (import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `.setAudience()` you have to pass all client `ID`'s. You can get the `ID` for your client from the [Credentials Page](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials). It's explained [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating#add_google_play_services).

Thanks to **@StevenSoneff**.

#### If you didn't get the basic concept

For every client you want your server to accept, you need to create a project in the `Developer Console`. Clients are differentiated by their `SHA-1` fingerprint. You can for example have a debug project (will take your debug fingerprint) and a release one. To make both work, you have to add both `ID`'s to your server's `GoogleIdTokenVerifier`'s `.setAudience()`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, If you're using Firebase to get the id token on Android or iOS. You should follow these instructions to verify it on your backend server.

[Verify ID tokens using a third-party JWT library](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens?hl=en#verify_id_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library)

For me, I'm using `Google OAuth Client` as the third-party library so it's easy to use.
But it's a little bit different from this document.

[Verify the Google ID token on your server side](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth)

1. The `CLIENT_ID` is your firebase project ID.
2. The `Issuer` has to be set as `https://securetoken.google.com/<projectId>`.
3. You need to use `GooglePublicKeysManager` and call `setPublicCertsEncodedUrl` to set it as `https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com`

```
GooglePublicKeysManager manager = new GooglePublicKeysManager.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY)
                .setPublicCertsEncodedUrl(PUBLIC_KEY_URL)
                .build();

GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(manager)
                .setAudience(Collections.singletonList(FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID))
                .setIssuer(ISSUER)
                .build();
```

If you have multiple issuers, then you have to create `GoogleIdTokenVerifier` for each one.